# WPF DataGrid control showing extra column

Tags: wpf, excel, datagrid

I am working on an application that reads three Excel files into DataTables. They are called Variants, Kits and Parts. Variants and Kits are connected with a DataRelation, as are Kits and Parts.

In one part of the program I use a DataGrid control to show the contents of the entire Variants table through a DataView. The problem is that after all the actual columns in the Variants table, the DataGrid shows one final column called VariantsKits, which is the name of the DataRelation between the Variants and Kits tables.

What can I do to not show this? I use AutoGenerateColumns since I don't know exactly which columns are in the imported Variants Excel file.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// You might have to add a reference to the dll first)
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
public PropertyType ThisIsThePropertyYouDontWantToShowUp { get; set; }
```

A second option would be to hook into the AutoGeneratingColumn event on
the DataGrid and have it cancel for the column you don't want

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(
    object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (/* do a check on e.PropertyName or e.PropertyType*/)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: The second approach obviously will be more in line with what you need if you don't actually have classes for your data types.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used your second suggestion and it worked well.